# find out strike out text of word document using java

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

Is there any way to find out that the text of a cell in a table in docx is strike out? Using java......

I have extracted tables from a word document. The tables contains strike out text too. I want to know if it is possible to know whether the text is strike out or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you have all the `XWPFTable t` you could use this method to find all the `run`s in the table and find out which is strike through. Run contains all the text that is formatted in the same way.

```
private void exploreTable(XWPFTable t) {
    for (XWPFTableRow row : t.getRows()) {
        for (XWPFTableCell c : row.getTableCells()) {
            for (XWPFParagraph p : c.getParagraphs()) {
                for (XWPFRun run : p.getRuns()) {
                    if(run.isStrikeThrough()) {.....}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```